# How to do batch insertion on Neo4J with Python

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, batch-insert

I have a code that insert many nodes and relationships:

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
from neo4jrestclient import client
import psycopg2

db = GraphDatabase("http://127.0.0.1:7474",username="neo4j", password="1234")

conn = psycopg2.connect("\
    dbname='bdTrmmTest'\
    user='postgres'\
    host='127.0.0.1'\
    password='1234'\
    ");

inicio = 0

while(inicio <= 4429640):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT p.latitude, p.longitude, h.precipitacaoh, h.datah, h.horah FROM pontos AS p, historico AS h WHERE p.gid = h.gidgeo_fk LIMIT 1640 OFFSET %d"%(inicio))

    sensorlatlong = db.labels.create("LaLo")
    sensorprecip = db.labels.create("Precipitacao")
    sensordata = db.labels.create("Data")
    sensorhora = db.labels.create("Hora")

    records = c.fetchall()

    for i in records:
        s2 = db.nodes.create(precipitacao=i[2])
        sensorprecip.add(s2)
        s5 = db.nodes.create(horah=i[4])
        sensorhora.add(s5)
        s5.relationships.create("REGISTROU",s2)
        q = 'MATCH (s:LaLo) WHERE s.latitude = "%s" AND s.longitude = "%s" RETURN s'%(str(i[0]),str(i[1]))
        results = db.query(q, returns=(client.Node))
        q2 = 'MATCH (s:LaLo)-->(d:Data)-->(h:Hora)-->(p:Precipitacao) WHERE s.latitude = "%s" AND s.longitude = "%s" AND d.datah = "%s" RETURN d'%(str(i[0]), str(i[1]), str(i[3]))
        results1 = db.query(q2, returns=(client.Node))   
        if (len(results) > 0):
            n = results[0].pop()
            if(len(results1) > 0):
                n1 = results1[0].pop()
                n1.relationships.create("AS", s5)
            else:
                s4 = db.nodes.create(datah=i[3])
                sensordata.add(s4)
                n.relationships.create("EM", s4)
                s4.relationships.create("AS",s5)
        else:
            s3 = db.nodes.create(latitude=i[0],longitude=i[1])
            sensorlatlong.add(s3)
            if(len(results1) > 0):
                n1 = results1[0].pop()
                n1.relationships.create("AS", s5)
            else:
                s4 = db.nodes.create(datah=i[3])
                sensordata.add(s4)
                s3.relationships.create("EM", s4)
                s4.relationships.create("AS",s5)

    inicio = inicio+1640
```

But it takes so many days to insert. How do batch insert in this code to decreasing the insertion time? I read this post http://jexp.de/blog/2012/10/parallel-batch-inserter-with-neo4j/ but it is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Neo4j from Python, but I'm pretty sure the client works the same way as in other languages, and that means your code will generate a lot of distinct HTTP connections, manipulating the low-level node and relationship endpoints. That means lots of latency.

It also generates lots of distinct queries, because it does string replacement instead using of parameterized queries, and Neo4j will have to parse each and everyone of them.

You'd be much better of with a small number of parameterized Cypher queries, or even one.

If I've read the [documentation for neo4jrestclient](http://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/info.html) correctly, I think it would look something like that:

```python
c.execute("SELECT p.latitude, p.longitude, h.precipitacaoh, h.datah, h.horah FROM pontos AS p, historico AS h WHERE p.gid = h.gidgeo_fk LIMIT 1640 OFFSET %d"%(inicio))

records = c.fetchall()

q = """
MERGE (lalo:LaLo {latitude: {latitude}, longitude: {longitude}})
WITH lalo
MERGE (lalo)-[:EM]->(data:Data {datah: {datah}})
WITH data
CREATE (data)-[:AS]->(hora:Hora {horah: {horah}})
CREATE (hora)-[:REGISTROU]->(:Precipitacao {precipitacao: {precipitacao}})
"""

for i in records:
    params = {
        "latitude": str(i[0]),
        "longitude": str(i[1]),
        "precipitacao": i[2],
        "datah": i[3],
        "horah": i[4],
    }
    db.query(q=q, params=params)
```

Of course, it will run faster if you have indices, so you'd need to create those first (at least the first 2), for example right before the loop, or outside of the process:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :LaLo(latitude)
CREATE INDEX ON :LaLo(longitude)
CREATE INDEX ON :Data(datah)
```

The last thing you could do to speed things up is [use transactions](http://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transactions.html), so writes happen in batches.

1. Open a transaction

   ```
   tx = db.transaction(for_query=True)
   ```
2. Append (for example) up to a thousand queries (or less if you reach the end of the rows)

   ```
   params = // ...
   tx.append(q=q, params=params)
   ```
3. Commit the transaction

   ```
   tx.execute()
   ```
4. Repeat until you've run out of rows from the SQL database